# Different User Roles from Different Firebase Collections Node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, authentication, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to understand how I can present two different views for each type of user that I have via Node js. I have 2 different types of users, 'restaurants' and 'customers'. Both users need to login in. However, the profile page of each type of user is a little different. Currently, both 'restaurants' and 'customers' are in different collections. I'd like to redirect the restaurant users to 'restaurant.hbs' and the customers to 'customer.hbs' with their corresponding information from the database.

Here is the Firebase functionality which enables the login of a user for either customer or restaurant owner.

```
firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then(({user}) => {
            // Get the user's ID token as it is needed to exchange for a session cookie.
            console.log(user)
            return user.getIdToken().then(idToken => {
                // Session login endpoint is queried and the session cookie is set.
                // CSRF protection should be taken into account.
                // ...
                console.log(idToken)
                return fetch("/sessionLogin", {
                    method: "POST",
                    headers: {
                      Accept: "application/json",
                      "Content-Type": "application/json",
                      "CSRF-Token": Cookies.get("XSRF-TOKEN"),
                    },
                    body: JSON.stringify({ idToken }),
                  });
            });
        }).then(() => {
        // A page redirect would suffice as the persistence is set to NONE.
        return firebase.auth().signOut();
        }).then(() => {
        window.location.assign('/profile');
        });
```

Here is what I have written for the page redirect for restaurants

```
function renderRestaurantPage(restaurantId, res) {
  getRestaurant(restaurantId).then(data => {
    let ambassadorPromise = getAmbassadorInfo(restaurantId)
    let activityPromise = getActivityFeed(restaurantId)

    var restaurantName = data['name']
    var totalScans = data['total_scans']

    Promise.all([ambassadorPromise, activityPromise]).then(values => {
        let ambassadorInfo = values[0]
        let activityInfo = values[1]

        let ambassadorList = []
        let activityList = []

        ambassadorInfo.forEach(element => {
            ambassadorList.push(element.data())
        })

        activityInfo.forEach(element => {
            activityList.push(element.data())
        });

        res.render('index', {restaurantName, totalScans, ambassadorList, activityList})
    })
  })
}

app.get("/profile", function (req, res) {
  console.log("We are about to look at session cookie")
  const sessionCookie = req.cookies.session || "";

  console.log("Printing session cookie")
  console.log(sessionCookie)
  admin
    .auth()
    .verifySessionCookie(sessionCookie, true /** checkRevoked */)
    .then((decodedClaims) => {
      console.log(decodedClaims.user_id)
      renderRestaurantPage(decodedClaims.user_id, res)
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error)
    });
});

app.post('/sessionLogin', (req, res) => {
  console.log("in session login")
  console.log(req.body)

  const idToken = req.body.idToken;
  // Guard against CSRF attacks.
  // if (csrfToken !== req.cookies.csrfToken) {
  //   res.status(401).send('UNAUTHORIZED REQUEST!');
  //   return;
  // }
  // Set session expiration to 5 days.
  const expiresIn = 60 * 60 * 24 * 5 * 1000;
  // Create the session cookie. This will also verify the ID token in the process.
  // The session cookie will have the same claims as the ID token.
  // To only allow session cookie setting on recent sign-in, auth_time in ID token
  // can be checked to ensure user was recently signed in before creating a session cookie.
  admin
    .auth()
    .createSessionCookie(idToken, { expiresIn })
    .then(
      (sessionCookie) => {
        // Set cookie policy for session cookie.
        const options = { maxAge: expiresIn, httpOnly: true, secure: true };
        res.cookie('session', sessionCookie, options);
        res.end(JSON.stringify({ status: 'success' }));
        console.log("cookie created")
      },
      (error) => {
        res.status(401).send('UNAUTHORIZED REQUEST!');
      }
    );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be managing the users 'type' from the users custom claims, this allows you to assign a user type as 'user' vs 'restaurant' that is accessible within your app and within your database.

For example, if the user is a restaurant, you would show buttons that allow the user to access a restaurant management panel, etc. The same would be done within Security Rules, where if the user's `token.restaurant == true` or `token.type == "restaurant"`

Custom Claims can only be edited from the admin-sdk, and you can read about them from [**here**](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims#set_and_validate_custom_user_claims_via_the_admin_sdk) and how to use them within Security Rules [**here**](https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/basics#custom-claim_attributes_and_roles).

Comment: I'll look into this, I solved my problem by creating 2 login menus, one for restaurants and one for customers. Then I saved the state, ie: restaurant, in the cookie.

Comment: the issue with cookies is that they are not tied to the account and can be cleared